# Run PHP Function with Text File

Tags: php

I am currently working on some code to check usernames and see if they are available. My ultimate  goal is to have the user be able to specify a text file with a username per line and have it run through them all and output if they are available or not. How can I make this happen? Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

function getTitle($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}

$resultCheck = getTitle("http://www.youtube.com/USERNAME");
if (strpos($resultCheck,'404') !== false) {
    echo 'Username Available';
}
else {
    echo 'Username Taken';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question differs quite a bit from the code you posted. Is your question how to read lines out of a file or how to correctly make a call to an external web-server?

Comment: Well what I am trying to do is read the lines out of a text file, run them through the function and find out which names are taken and which are not, and then display. But instead of specifying the username, I want to grab it from the lines of the text file, and either echo the ones that are taken/not taken, or write to the file and say "XNAME is taken!".

Comment: Just saying, Youtube seems to correctly return a `404` HTTP status message for not-found pages. So, you could make your program a lot more efficient by doing `HEAD` requests for different Youtube pages and simply checking the status. You'd also be a better internet community member by reducing the load being generated.

Comment: Well YouTube is not the primary site this will be, it was just a placeholder to TRY and make things easier. I did not know about this, but I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function getTitle($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
    }
    else
    return '404';
}
$mytextfile='names.txt';
$data = file_get_contents($mytextfile);
$convert = explode("\n", $data);

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    if (strlen($convert[$i])>0) {
        $resultCheck = getTitle("http://www.youtube.com/" . $convert[$i]);
        echo ' Username ' . $convert[$i];
        if (strpos($resultCheck,'404') !== false) {
            echo ' Available';
        }
        else {
            echo ' Taken';
        }
        echo "<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What the author is demonstrating but didn't mention is that it would be smart to first open your file of usernames, iterate it line by line and apply (check) each line (username) with your desired function (e.g. extracting html content from youtube).

Comment: This code definitely works for me, but is there anyway I could use the same code but with a text file the user uploads themselves?